# XACT support outside of XNA?

Tags: xna, c#, audio, xact

I was building a new game in Monogame when I realized that it didn't have XACT support like XNA did. I was wondering if anyone knew another framework that could be used with or instead of MonoGame (preferably with) to get the ability to load XACT projects into the game?

Comment: I wish people would give an explanation of why they vote a question down. Was my question format incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XACT itself is only supported on platforms that already support the official XNA framework (specifically Windows Desktop and Xbox; and not WP7). I'm not aware of any re-implementations of XACT for other platforms.

So your choices are basically to use the official XNA framework (if you only need Windows/Xbox support). Or select another audio technology (possibly `SoundEffect` in XNA/MonoGame, possibly something else).

Also keep in mind that XACT is no longer "supported" on Windows (similar to XNA - it's not broken - it will still *work* if you choose to use it).

Comment: Note that XACT is a DirectX API and not just an XNA API, however that doesn't change the platform support. (Source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform_Audio_Creation_Tool )

Comment: Mmmm - I meant to be clearer about that in my answer, that XACT is a technology in its own right, XNA just provides a wrapper - guess it didn't come across. In any case, [here's the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx) about it being no longer "supported" on Windows.

Comment: Link helps a lot. I also saw that a new XAudio technology is available in that same link. Do you know of any audio frameworks that have a similar feature set?